# Where should I install/save node_modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new in react development and also in using node js. I'm jus concern on where to save the node_modules folder thus where to install the node packages.

In current project, it is saved in "C:/Users/myUser/node_modules" and my project seem to work fine, it can see the node_modules when I hover in it's packages when I'm importing it.

I just don't know this, in production env, thus the client need to install those packages that we use in development env? If yes, then should I install the node_modules inside the project? I really don't know the right thing to do here. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `node_modules` goes at the root of the project and is ignored by source control. For example, if your project is at `C:\Users\myUser\someProject`:

You would want to have your `package.json` file at `someProject\package.json`. Then inside the `someProject` folder (the project root), you would run `npm install`. This will generate the `node_modules` folder at the same level.

Anyone else who grabs the project would run `npm install` at the project root on their machine as well since you typically don't check in `node_modules`.

Comment: Okay, this is very clear instructions. Thanks, I will do this.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Comment: Do you have a social media where we can chat? I have other questions about React. And base on your profile here, you seem to know well ReactJS. If you have time, kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I’m @ben_kane on Twitter. Feel free to DM me there and I’ll help if I can